# Bullet Not shooting correctly

Tags: java, animation, graphics, coordinates

I've been trying to make a bullet shoot when I click.  It partly works, but the thing is that it's moving with the ship instead up directly up (like I want it to go).

I think this may be due to the fact that the `x` and `y` coordinates are pointing to the ship is there any way around this? Here is my code:

```
 package galaga.display.players;

import galaga.display.Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Bullet {
    private  int x;
    private  int y;
    private final int size = 16;
    public boolean hasClicked;
    Rectangle bullet;
    public Bullet() {


        setX(Game.getPlayer1().getX()+Game.getPlayer1().getSize()/3);
        setY(Game.getPlayer1().getY()-Game.getPlayer1().getSize());

    }
    private void setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    private void setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public void render(Graphics g){
        if(hasClicked){
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(x,y, size, size);
        }

    }

    public void update(Game game){

        if(hasClicked){


            y--;

        }

    }
}
```

Here is my Ship/PLayer Class :

```
package galaga.display.players;

import galaga.display.Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Players {
    public boolean isUp,isDown,isLeft,isRight;
    private int x, y;
    private int size = 50;
    private BufferedImage image2;
    private Rectangle boundingBox;
    boolean hasCollided = false;
    public Players(int x,int y) {
        setY(y);
        setX(x);
        try {
            image2 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Anonymous\\Desktop\\SpaceShip.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setBoundingBox(new Rectangle(x,y,size,size));

    }
    private void setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }
    private void setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
    public int getSize(){
        return size;
    }
    public void render(Graphics g){


        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawImage(image2,x,y,size,size,null);

    }
    public void update(Game game){
        Rectangle rect = game.getRectangle();
        getBoundingBox().setBounds(x, y, size, size);

        if(isUp){
            y--;
        }
        else if (isDown){
            y++;
        }
        else if(isLeft){
            x--;
        }
        else if(isRight){
            x++;
        }

        if (x < 0 || x + size >= rect.width) {
            // change the direction
            x *= -1;
        }
        if (y < 0 || y + size >=rect.height) {
            // change the direction
            y*= -1;
        }



    }
    public Rectangle getBoundingBox() {
        return boundingBox;
    }
    public void setBoundingBox(Rectangle boundingBox) {
        this.boundingBox = boundingBox;
    }

}
```

Comment: why do you create a new Bullet object every time the user clicks?

Comment: @RedAlert So that a new bullet is displayed when it clicks

Comment: You should not be using static variables here, other than the SIZE constant. Each Bullet should have its own unique x and y position fields, and if your fields are static, you lose that.

Comment: why not simply redraw it? You know, using that render method you already have?

Comment: Am I wrong or is this code generating a new bullet every time it updates the graphic, not every time he clicks.

Comment: Could not get your answer from Dream.In.Code? http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/341956-galaga-bullet-not-shooting-correctly/

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl no I couldnt

Comment: Why were your fields non-static in dream in code and now static (and broken) here?

Comment: @RedAlert I can't because it requires a parameter of Graphics and my Update method doesent have that I have it set up so that the update method keeps updating the other classes and the render method keeps rendering the render methods from the player and bullet class

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am trying something different now

Comment: @user3000477: ... and wrong. Get rid of the static modifiers.

Comment: Use a vector for bullets for the love of God. Also, check the comment in you DIC post I left you.

Comment: You really need to read the definition of the Java keyword static -- it's not doing what you think it does. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.cokeandcode.com/info/tut2d.html) to get a better idea of how to set up your game. I might be going out on a limb, but I'm willing to bet that you have bigger structural issues that you haven't noticed yet.

Comment: @user3000477 I'm sorry, constantly making new Bullet objects completely defeats the purpose of having a class in the first place, which is to keep track of their x and y positions. You need to change your update method to redraw the current bullet, not make a brand new one. Also, fix your static variables.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl So that will fix that when I click the bullet appears where I originally started and not where I currently am?

Comment: @leigero no its every time it updates the game only if the user has clicked

Comment: @user3000477 no, it's just a suggestion. Also, the mods will most likely be flagged for the length of this comment stream...

Comment: wait, is `update()` called each time the player fires a new bullet? Why on earth is that a method in your Bullet class?

Comment: @RedAlert no its called every time the game updates in my game class

Answer (score 0):

**Static Variables:**
As many have stated there are a few issues with the code beyond the bullet not being where you want it to be. First of all your static variables should not be static.

Static variables are not unique to each instance of the object and remain constant across all objects of that class. (IE Every bullet will have the same `x` `y` coordinates).

**Update Method:**
Also I have no idea when or how you are calling the `update()` method, but if you are only calling the update method when a user clicks then your bullet is only going to move when a user clicks... IE they have to pump the bullet up the screen via clicking.

You probably want to call the update method in your main game's update method so that the bullet is updated and redrawn with the game itself.

Lastly your update method should not be creating new bullets, it just needs to update the `x` and `y` coordinates of that bullet and redraw it, or in your case, just the `y` variable.

```
package galaga.display.players;

import galaga.display.Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Bullet {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private final int size = 16;
    Rectangle bullet;
    public Bullet() {

        setX(Game.getPlayer1().getX()+Game.getPlayer1().getSize()/3);
        setY(Game.getPlayer1().getY()-Game.getPlayer1().getSize());
    }
    private void setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    private void setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public static void render(Graphics g){  // Call this in your main game's paint method

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(x,y, size, size);
        }
    }

    public static void update(Game game){
     //removed the creating a new bullet from the update.
            y--;
    }
}
```

Lastly I removed the `hasClicked` variable. It doesn't make much sense to have a bullet with a `hasClicked` variable, since the bullet should never care if a user is clicking, that's something the main game should worry about.

Additionally you set `hasClicked` to true in the constructor, and never modified the value or changed it to false so it will always be true and therefore it's pointless anyhow.

Comment: as I stated It is being called in when the update method is called in my game class which is being called every couple milliseconds i think the thing is that if I move my ship and click the bullet just appears where the ship was originally located at the start and then moves up.

Comment: @user3000477 That is because you have the `new Bullet()` inside the update method. Every few milliseconds your game is making a new bullet and re-drawing it where your ship is. So when your ship moves up, the new bullets you are constantly creating are moving up as well.

Comment: No its drawing it at the location I set it to I wan't it to find my ship and then shoot from where my ship is, I start from the middle of the screen and then I move and I click and the bullet appears in the middle of the screen and moves up

Comment: @user3000477 If I understand you correctly your bullets are only appearing where your ship STARTS and when your ship moves your bullets still spawn at the ships starting location? This tells me there's something wrong with the way you're updating the ships `x` `y` coordinates or the getter methods.

Comment: Yes exactly and if I do update the x and y coordinates the bullet just follows my ship around

Comment: @user3000477 Yes, it would help to see your ship class. Your bullet class should get its initial `x` `y` coordinates from the ship's current `x` `y` coordinates, then the bullet update method would only change the bullet's X Y coords. Because your bullet shows up in the wrong place tells me you're getting the wrong info from your ship class.

Comment: I tried this to update my bullets location it does render where its supposed to but it only moves where my ship moves :
 public void update(Game game){

  if(hasClicked){
   new Bullet();
   setX(Game.getPlayer1().getX()+Game.getPlayer1().getSize()/3);
   setY(Game.getPlayer1().getY()-Game.getPlayer1().getSize());
   y--;

  }

 }

Comment: @user3000477 It is too difficult to understand your problem through comments. You'll have to post your ship class in your question or I can't help you.

Comment: I have added my ship class